# BPXBATCH claims condition code 0, but touch request did not work

Tags: zos, jcl

I'm submitting a JCL request to create a file to indicate that a particular JCL job completed successfully or not. This is necessary because we only have access to job status via SSH. The system reports condition code 0, yet the file is not "touch"ed.

JCL:

```
//WOODSMNX JOB (1111),MSGLEVEL=(1,1),CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=H,
//  USER=WOODSMN,REGION=0M
/*JOBPARM S=CLA
//**********************************
//*  CREATE SUCCESS INDICATOR FILE *
//**********************************
//SUCCIND EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH
//STDERR DD SYSOUT=*
//STDOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//STDPARM DD *
SH 
 touch /tmp/SSC.D051721.T200335.S90.CP037.DONE.SUCCESS
/*
//
```

The job is actually stored in a ZFS file, and is submitted via ssh through Unix System Services. However, I have tried submitting this JCL through ISPF, with the only difference being that it was stored in RECFM=FB,LRECL=80 PDS. Why would it give me a false sense of success?

Comment: I'd suggest rewording your question, as the answer to your question is that BPXBATCH is returning 0 because BPXBATCH didn't fail.  I'd suggest using SYSAFF statements to ensure you're running on the same system for all jobs.

Answer (score 1):

From a previous discussion regarding parallel shell session, I still believe that you're working on y multi-system sysplex, don't you? Be aware that each system has its own `/tmp`. Therefore if the job runs on system A and you're logged in to system B, you will not see the "touched" file.

Also from that previous discussion, I believe your sysplex is **not** running with shared UNIX file systems. You should make sure all access to UNIX files and directories is consitently done from a single, and always the same system.

One more thing to consider: The `/tmp` is probably a temporary file system (i.e. main storage (RAM) only). All content will be lost after an IPL. If there was an IPL between the time your Job runs, and the time you're checking what file has been created to denote the job result, you'd be lost. Neither file would be found. Better choose a location that stores data permanently, e.g. `/var/jobname/result`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go to [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=environments-bpxbatch) and scroll down to the section titled "General rules for setting return codes" to see if adding `set -o errexit` will give you the result you want.

Comment: Another simple idea is to add an additional line to the script to display the actual return value from "touch"...adding another line like echo "Touch RC = $?" > /dev/console would put the RC on the system console (or anywhere else you like) if there's any doubt about what happened.